# How to divide Android game screen

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I am working on a game application and in a `horizontal orientation`.

I use the **left 1/3 of the screen** for displaying scores and controls and the **right 2/3 for displaying** my game board.

My game works as is, but **I currently use a single canvas** to display everything.  This makes my game logic more complicated because I must always add 1/3 of the screen width when displaying any graphics.

Seems like **I should be able to define 2 sections of the scree**n (left 1/3 and right 2/3), maybe using two canvases, such that each section provide me a unique coordinate system starting at 0,0.  This would make my game coordinate math much easier.

**Can I use multiple Canvases in one activity?**  Can I place them wherever I'd like?

Thanks

Comment: the best way is to use fragments to make section for the screen or you can use weight concept in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use weights in linear layout
which are used to divide the layout as desired ratio
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight
Fragments
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

use fragments for second layout

example

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.33333"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
<--fragment here -->

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.6666"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark" >
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is the difference between using weights in a layout vs doing it with fragments?

Comment: Weight are used to divide the screen as our desired rato
Fragment are used as part of screenview where you can add another view of type fragment over it and you can replace the view
refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use fragments for dividing the screens.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use [fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) or [Fragment video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GyGtCMoR_U&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW4lMlpHgL7UNQSGMERcDzHo), identify 3 fragments and in let in each fragment have a canvas